# Sharepoint document library: Folder creation and folder rename

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

Really sorry as title of my question is not so clear. Here is the actual problem.

I am  creating Folder in Document Library using `LIST.asmx` service and updating url of folder in database.

But suppose in future any user rename the folder name then still that folder should open from "**url**" which we stored on database is the requirement.
Note: I can not update database url when I rename folder.

Tried lot to search on th.at but no luck. Please suggest me so that I can try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FolderPath = "http://YOUR-SharePoint-Site/sites/sales/documents/Invoices";

SPFolder TargetFolder = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFolder(FolderPath);

Target.Item["Name"] = "Invoices 2014";

Target.Item.Update();
```

Read more: [Here](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/10/how-to-rename-sharepoint-folder-programmatically.html#ixzz3acXxFfxm)

`

Answer (score 0):

As per SharePoint best practices, Any update directly to the database is not going to a viable solution and supported.  so use only the object model or CSOM or the supported way for this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to find about "object model or CSOM" not get useful information, could you provided any link if you have. I am new in sharepoint.